# Which people and how many were boarded onto the ferries?

Tags: dc, the-dark-knight

In *The Dark Knight*, Joker announces that people will have to live by his rules from now on, and warns them against escaping through bridges and tunnels. Authorities try to save people from him by boarding them onto ferries.

The question is, how many people were onboard the ferries when they were hijacked? All of Gotham's city's general population? Some of them chosen randomly? Or specific ones? What was the criteria by which they were chosen?

Comment: *Women and children, follow me, your Captain to safety!*

Comment: @F1Krazy you edited out the second part of my question. Can you please put it back

Comment: @SyedAqeelAshiq I edited the second question out because otherwise, your post risked being closed as too broad. You should only ask one question at a time, and you were trying to ask two. If you still want to know why only two ferries were involved in the evacuation, you need to post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were approximately 30,000 people *waiting* for ferry service. They doesn't appear to be any particular criteria for their presence, other than that they were those who couldn't secure a suitable route out of the east side of the city and had been shepherded there by the authorities.

Note that when we cut back to the shore after boarding has occurred, that there aren't jostling crowds more people waiting and the other ferry is willing to double-back and collect the prisoners next when their sister ship's engines fail (e.g. instead of just leaving them there and collecting more law-abiding citizens) so, in the absence of any reason to think otherwise, we should presumably assume that they *all* managed to board.

> “My officers are going over every inch of the tunnels and bridges,”
> Gordon was saying, “but with the Joker’s threat . . .”
>
> “Land routes east?” the mayor asked.
>
> “Backed up for hours. Which leaves the ferries with thirty thousand
> waiting to board. Plus, corrections are at capacity, so I want to use
> the ferry to take some prisoners off the island.”
>
> “The men you and Dent put away? Those aren’t people I’m worried
> about.”
>
> “You should be. They’re the people you least want to be stuck with in
> an emergency. Whatever the Joker’s planning, it’s a good bet that
> Harvey’s prisoners might be involved. I want ’em out of here.”
>
> Gordon prevailed. An hour later, officers in riot gear escorted
> citizens off one of the ferries and felons on. Nobody was happy.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Dark Knight - Official Novelisation](https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_(novelization))</sup></sub>

and

> The first ferry was chugging away from its dock and into the bay as
> the moon became visible through clouds, a fuzzy white disc. As soon as
> the traffic cops signaled the deckhands to lift the boarding barrier
> on the second ferry, hundreds of people surged aboard, some burdened
> with luggage, some wearing fur coats, some dressed as though for a
> beach outing, despite the chilly air. Within minutes, it, too, pulled
> out into the choppy water, heading for the western shore, the
> mainland, safety.

For the record, this doesn't seem like it would be unrealistic. The [Staten Island Ferry](https://www1.nyc.gov/html/dot/html/ferrybus/ferry-facts.shtml) (for example) can comfortably host 5000 passengers. Packed in and ignoring normal safety considerations, you could easily carry 30,000 people, probably more.